# Is it safe when open and close multiple SQLiteDatabse connection

Tags: android, sqlite

ex)

### Table : playlist

create_no INT,
music_id INT

### Table : music

music_id INT,
music_name VARCHAR(50),
music_data VARCHAR(50)... etc

```
public class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
//...
public List<Music> getPlayList()
{
    List<Music> resultList = new ArrayList<Music>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    //getplaylist
    for(;;)
    {
        resultList.add(getMusic(music_id));
    }

    db.close();
    return resultList;
}

public Music getMusic(int music_id)
{
    Music resultMusic;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //get Music
    db.close();
    return resultMusic;
}
}
```

Is it OK that when open SQLiteDatabase Object and close in another ──get and open SQLiteDatabaseObject── method?

Sorry for my poor English...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok but it's a lot of waste of time.

Create a Singleton object or a property of your Application object and use it always to read.